# VB.NET Event occur only once at midnight

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

I have a service that runs all day that supports my application. At midnight, I want this service to transfer data between tables and I want this event to occur ONLY ONCE. The service refreshes every 15 seconds. Can I just check if it is between 12:00:00 and 12:00:15 and that work? Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is the final task before my application is finished.

Comment: You might want to add a function that detect if the transfer was done. Then you could do: If Not TransferWasDoneToday() Then DoTransfer(). It also find it weird that your service need to be refreshed every 15sec, what do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: The existing service was not written by me and is not actually a service... more like an .exe that runs all day